# Replace em substring no c#

Tags: c#

Texto original:

```
E02000000000000002DOCE LUAMAR MORENINHA 240G                                  00100309        00100309
```

Preciso mudar para isso:

```
E02000000000000002DOCE LUAMAR MORENINHA 240G                                  20100309        20100309
```

Estou usando isso:

```cs
if (str.Substring(0, 4) == "E020")
{
    if (str.Substring(78, 2) == "00")
    {
        string str2 = str.Replace(str.Substring(78, 2), "20");
```

Mas o resultado está saindo assim:

```
E02202020202020202DOCE LUAMAR MORENINHA 240G                                  20120309        20120309
```

Está colocando 20 em todo os lugares quem tem 00 na linha. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Esses conjuntos de número que você quer alterar é sempre de 08 números e começam com 00?

Comment: @jbueno Desculpe o revert, mas a posição dos espaços é importante e colocando como citação, vários espaços são renderizados no HTML como um só.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método `Remove`para remover uma parte da `string`, passando como parâmetros o indice de ínicio da remoção e quantos caracteres você quer remover e em seguida utilizar o método `Insert` para inserir a `string` que você deseja, passando como parâmetros o índice de onde você quer inserir a `string` e a `string` que você quer inserir.

Dessa forma:

```
var str2 = str.Remove(78, 2).Insert(78, "20");
```

Comment: obrigado ajudou, fiquei meio confuso pq eu tbm tenho que mudar os caracteres numero (94, 2), tive que fazer em 2 etapas

Comment: @FarofakidsTrader fico feliz em poder ajudar. Caso tenha sido útil esta minha resposta e estiver disposto, por favor, marcar como resposta para que possa ajudar outras pessoas também. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Isso acontece porque o método `Replace` recebe um valor para procurar e substituir como primeiro parâmetro. Nesse parâmetro você passa:

```
str.Substring(78, 2)
```

Que, no caso, é `00`. Em outras palavras, você deu ao programa a ordem de trocar todas as ocorrências de `00` por `20`.

Se você deseja trocar somente dois caracteres específicos, nos índices 78 a 80, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
str2 = str.Substring(0, 78) + "20" + str.Substring(80);
```

Ou algo similar.

Comment: grato deu certo tbm asism

Answer (score 0):

Se os dois conjuntos de números finais sempre forem iguais, como no exemplo, você pode fazer assim, caso não queira ficar preso ao comprimento da `string`.

```
    var s = "E02000000000000002DOCE LUAMAR MORENINHA 240G                                  00100309        00100309";

    string[] array = s.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    s = s.Replace(array[array.Length - 1], "2" + array[array.Length - 1].Remove(0,1));

   //Retorna
             E02000000000000002DOCE LUAMAR MORENINHA 240G                                  20100309        20100309
```

O mesmo funciona para uma `string` de outro comprimento.

```
 s = "E020DOCE LUAMAR  2G        00100309   00100309";

//Retorna
      E020DOCE LUAMAR  2G        20100309   20100309
```